# Does the .equals() method of the double wrapper class work for finding equality of floating point numbers?

Tags: java, floating-point

I know that for primitive floating point types (floats and doubles), you're not supposed to compare them directly via `==`. But what if you're using the wrapper class for double? Will something like

```
Double a = 5.05;
Double b = 5.05; 
boolean test = a.equals(b);
```

compare the two values properly?

Comment: I'd expect it to work in the same places where `==` works (with a few caveats around NaN values). The reason why `==` is usually a bad idea for doubles is that two values that are obtained as the result of calculations can be microscopically different - in which case `Double.equals` will still return false, because the values aren't equal.

Comment: Quickly testing the above in JShell reveals that it doesn't work in the same places where `==` works as mentioned above. `boolean test = a.equals(b); test ==> true` and  `boolean test = a == b; test ==> false`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to fully understand the reason for why `==`  comparison is a bad idea. Without understanding, you're just fumbling in the dark.

Let's talk about how computers (and doubles) work.

Imagine you enter a room; it has 3 lightswitches, otherwise it is bare. You will enter the room, you can fiddle with the switches, but then you have to leave. I enter the room later and can look at the switches.

How much information can you convey?

The answer is: You can convey 8 different states: DDD, DDU, DUD, DUU, UDD, UDU, UUD, and UUU. That's it.

Computers work exactly like this when they store a double. Except instead of 3 switches, you get 64 switches. That means `2^64` different states you can convey with a single `double`, and that's a ton of states: That's a 19 digit number.

But it's still a finite amount of states, and that's problematic: There are an infinite amount of numbers between 0 and 1. Let alone between -infinity and +infinity, which `double` dares to cover. How do you store one of an infinite infinity of choices when you only get to represent `2^64` states? That 19-digit number starts to look pretty small when it's tasked to differentiate from an infinite infinity of possibilities, doesn't it?

The answer, of course, is that **this is completely impossible**.

So doubles don't actually work like that. Instead, someone took some effort and hung up a gigantic numerline, from minus infinite to plus infinite, in a big room, and threw `2^64` darts at this line. The numbers they landed on are the 'blessed numbers' - these are representable by a `double` value. That does mean there are an infinite amount of numbers between any 2 darts that therefore are *not* representable. The darts aren't quite random: The closer you are to 0, the denser the darts. Once you get beyond about `2^52` or so, the distance between 2 darts exceeds 1.0 even.

Here's a trivial example of a non-representable number: 0.3. Amazing, isn't it? Something that simple. It means **a computer literally cannot calculate 0.1 + 0.2 using `double`**. So what happens when you try? The rules state that the result of any calculation is always silently rounded to the nearest blessed number.

And therein lies the rub: You can run the math:

```
double x = 0.1 + 0.2;
```

and later do:

```
double y = 0.9 - 0.8 + 0.15 + 0.05;
```

and us humans would immediately notice that `x` and `y` are naturally identical. But **not so for computers** - because of that silent rounding to the nearest blessed number, it's possible that `x` is `0.29999999999999999785`, and `y` is `0.300000000000000000012`.

Thus we get to four crucial aspects when using `double` (or `float` which is just about worse in every fashion, don't ever use those):

- If you need absolute precision, don't use them at all.
- When printing them, always round them down. System.out.println does this out of the box, but you should really use `.printf("%.5f")` or similar: Pick the # of digits you need.
- Be aware that the errors will compound, and it gets worse as you are further away from 1.0.
- Do not ever compare with `==`, instead always use a delta-compare: The notion of "lets consider the 2 numbers equal if they are within 0.0000000001 of each other".

There is no universal magic delta value; it depends on your precision needs, how far you away from 1.0, etc. Therefore, just asking the computer: Hey, just figure this stuff out I just wanna know if these 2 doubles are equal is **impossible**. The only definition available that doesn't require your input as to 'how close' they can be, is the notion of sheer perfection: They are equal only if they are precisely identical. This definition would fail you in that trivial example above. It makes not one iota of difference if you use `Double.equals` instead of `double == double`, or any other utility class for that matter.

So, no, `Double.equals` is not suitable. You will have to compare `Math.abs(d1 - d2) < epsilon`, where epsilon is your choice. Mostly, if equality matters at all you're already doing it wrong and shouldn't be using `double` in the first place.

NB: When representing money, you don't want unpredictable rounding, so never use doubles for these. Instead figure out what the atomic banking unit is (dollarcents, eurocents, yen, satoshis for bitcoin, etc), and store that as a long. You store $4.52 and `long x = 452;`, not as `double x = 4.52;`.

Comment: Re “They are equal only if they are precisely identical”: This is not reliable either. Just as two results that would be equal if calculated with real-number arithmetic may differ if calculated in different ways with floating-point arithmetic, so too can two results that would be inequal if calculated with real-number arithmetic may be equal if calculated with floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, I did. Answer edited, thanks :)